# Difference between int[] and Integer[] array while converting into List

Tags: java, arrays, list, wrapper

According to basics
-->int[] is array of primitive 
-->and Integer[] is object array

But I am not able to understand the behavior when you convert both into List. Please refer the example to understand the question

## scenerio 1:

```
int [] a1={2,10,55,60};

    /** To covert it into List

     **/
    List list  = (Arrays.asList(a1));
    System.out.println("size :"+list.size());
    Iterator it =list.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(it.next());
    }
```

the out put for the above code is **size :1
[I@f74f6ef(Address )**

## scenerio 2:

```
     Integer [] a1={2,10,55,60};

    /** To covert it into List

     **/
    List list  = (Arrays.asList(a1));
    System.out.println("size :"+list.size());
    Iterator it =list.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(it.next());
    }
```

the out put for the above code is **size :4

2
10
55
60**

Now one reason could be that the a1(int) might be holding all the elements of the array with address as Address+4(int) for consecutive elements. and whereas a1 (Integer) would be holding the address of each and every element. 
so might be reason that the size in case of int is **1 and in Integer its 4**.
I am not sure with the above statement. can some one please help me to understand the situation??

Comment: Don't use raw types. If you do `List<Integer> list = (Arrays.asList(a1));` the compiler will give you an incompatible types error which partially explains it.

Comment: Hi Radiodef Please share me the link of the original question. So that I can    clear my doubt

Comment: The duplicate link is at the top of the question body. (Refresh the page.) The answer is that `Arrays.asList(a1)` creates a `List<int[]>`.

Comment: @vinodbazari It's at the top of the question, in a yellow box.

Comment: @Radiodef :  thnx .....